# how to read a char value in C without going to next line

Tags: c, types, char, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{

       char p,q;
       printf("Hello enter char: ");
       p=getchar();
       printf("the char is: %c\n",p);

       printf("Hello enter char: ");
       q=getchar();
       printf("the char is: %c\n",q);
    return 0;
}
```

(WHY IS MY OUTPUT for the second printf and scanf not waiting for me to input a char before exiting the program?.....what i mean is u know where it says q=getchar();??? shouldnt it wait for to input a char before exiting the program? but for some reason the program just exits when it goes to the next line...

Comment: To what `scanf()` are you referring to? And when you "entered" your character *and pressed the <enter> key* on your keyboard, how many characters do you think you entered? Hint: it isn't one.

Comment: i see the first print out on the screen, then i type in one char, then press enter...then the computer prints out the second AND third print out....why isnt it just printing out the second printout and wait until i press enter after typing a char?

Comment: @HardyFeng oh thankyou!!! thats the problem...so please tell me how to fix this??

Comment: Enter key is also taken as input.

Comment: Add another getchar() to accept the return key is a option.

Comment: And `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`, despite the name.

Answer (score 1):

when pressing enter,a character '\n' is inputing.So your getchar() was used before you enter the second character.I think you want the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char p,q;
    printf("Hello enter char: ");
    p=getchar();
    printf("the char is: %c\n",p);

    int c; 
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF && c != ' ') ; 

    printf("Hello enter char: ");
    q=getchar();
    printf("the char is: %c\n",q);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `getchar()` returns `int`, if `c` is `char`, you'll have some problem with `EOF` checking.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `getch()` instead of `getchar()` to avoid pressing enter key.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void) 
{

       char p,q;
       printf("Hello enter char: ");
       p=getch();
       printf("the char is: %c\n",p);

       printf("Hello enter char: ");
       q=getch();
       printf("the char is: %c\n",q);
       return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When encountering invalid user inputs, use getchar() to read char, and other similar instances where there are undesired characters stuck at input stream(like in your case it was a newline) I define a constant named FLUSH

```
   #define FLUSH while(getchar() != '\n')
```

to solve the problem. What this statement does is that it reads a character and then throws it away. Now if you try to place it after one of your getchars i.e.

```
   p=getchar();
   printf("the char is: %c\n",p);
   FLUSH;
```

it will read the newline then stops because the condition within the while statement no longer holds.

Note: Using getchar() for prompts leaves a '\n' in the input stream you will find this troublesome once you make another prompt and have not eradicated that '\n'.